# Looping through elements of a list and then appending to a new list

Tags: r

I've been trying to write code that would allow me to loop through the items of the list, each of which is a vector of numeric values. For elements of the vector meets a certain criterion, then I want to append those numbers to a new list that also contains a vector of numeric values.

My dataset is structured like the following:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 .... Col29
-11   -10  -9  ....   15
-13   -12  -11 ....   14
```

I've tried the following code thus far:

```
new_list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(time_list)) {
  for(j in 1:length(time_list[[i]]) {
    if(!is.na(time_list[[i]][j]) & time_list[[i]][j] >= 0) {
      # I am stuck here, as all the code I've run gives me an error.
    }
  }
}
```

I want a list that's structured pretty much the same as the original, but keeping only numbers greater than or equal to 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a close `)`  to close the `is.na`. Also, though maybe there will be no problem, instead of `1:length(time_list)`, use `seq_along(time_list)`. And the same for `1:length(time_list[[i]])`.

Comment: I just fixed that. It's actually there in R--just made a typo here :)

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Hi, Ken. I get a warning whenever I try `new_list[[i]][j] <= time_list[[i][j]`. I am sure my logic is wrong, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: can you use `dput(time_list)`? Without actually seeing your data it is hard to be sure what the problem is

Comment: `144 = structure(list(Time_1 = -13L, Time_2 = -12L, Time_3 = -11L, 
        Time_4 = -10L, Time_5 = -9L, Time_6 = -8L, Time_7 = -7L, 
        Time_8 = -6L, Time_9 = -5L, Time_10 = -4L, Time_11 = -3L, 
        Time_12 = -2L, Time_13 = -1L, Time_14 = 0L, Time_15 = 1L...` That's a snippet of the output.

Answer (score 1):

I will call your data `df` like

```
df <- structure(list(Time_1 = -13L, Time_2 = -12L, Time_3 = -11L, Time_4 = -10L, 
        Time_5 = -9L, Time_6 = -8L, Time_7 = -7L, Time_8 = -6L, Time_9 = -5L, 
        Time_10 = -4L, Time_11 = -3L, Time_12 = -2L, Time_13 = -1L, Time_14 = 0L, 
        Time_15 = 1L))

is.pos <- function(x){
  (!is.na(x)) & (x >= 0)
}
```

The function will check whether we are dealing with a positive number and return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. We'll use this for indexing:

```
is.pos(df)
# Time_1  Time_2  Time_3  Time_4  Time_5  Time_6  Time_7  Time_8  Time_9 Time_10 
# FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE 
# Time_11 Time_12 Time_13 Time_14 Time_15 
# FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE 

df[is.pos(df)]
# $Time_14
# [1] 0
# 
# $Time_15
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Hi, Ken. This is good, but I need it be a list of vectors. I think the other poster's solution is what I want. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

From your above statement, it sounds like you only want to delete negative values from your list. If that is the case, then why don't you try something like this:

```
row1 <- c(-11,-10,-9,-7,0,3,15)
row2 <- c(-13,-12,-11,2,0,-7,14)

time_list <- rbind(row1,row2)
> time_list
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
row1  -11  -10   -9   -7    0    3   15
row2  -13  -12  -11    2    0   -7   14

time_list[time_list<0] <- NA
> time_list
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
row1   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    3   15
row2   NA   NA   NA    2    0   NA   14

new_time_list <- time_list[,colSums(is.na(time_list))<nrow(time_list)]
> new_time_list
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
row1   NA    0    3   15
row2    2    0   NA   14
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much.